# Use SED to replace string of fixed length at certain position - arbitrary pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Trying to replace a string of fixed length at certain position (a string of arbitrary numbers) with a specified string.

I have to :
 
for every line beginning with `1`, in the  `4-13` columns, replace existing value with `123456789` where column `4` is a space.  `123456789`

so a sample file looks like this in the first line:

```
110 000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and i want

```
110 123456789000000000000000000000000000000
```

So far I have:

```
sed -i "/^1/ s/(.{10})/ 123456789/4" $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt
```

This doesn't do anything though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^1/s/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{9\}\)/\1123456789/' "$DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt"
```

The preceding regex `/^1/` makes the following substitute command apply only to lines starting with a `1`.

The substitute command itself captures the first 4 chars `100<space>` and the following 9 chars `000000000` into separate groups while keeping the first 4 chars and replacing the following nine chars by `123456789`.

Btw, if you have GNU sed, you might simplify the command to:

```
sed -r  '/^1/s/(.{4})(.{9})/\1123456789/'
```

... which looks simpler for understanding, but is not portable across all different sed versions.

Comment: Awesome - thank you -- question though, why can't I use the /4 at the end like I was before to just start the pattern search at the 4th character?

Comment: I don't know where you have the `/4` from, but it is not valid `sed` syntax.

Comment: sed -r  '/^1/s/(.{4})(.{9})/\1123456789/'  this command is printing on the screen . how can i avoid that . mean i want it not to print on the screen insted what ever input_file given in that that output should get updated?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, simple to understand solution

```
awk '/^1/ {print substr($0,1,4)"123456789"substr($0,14)}' file
110 123456789000000000000000000000000000000
```

If line starts with `1`, print the `4` first characters + `123456789` + the rest of the line starting from  `14` position.

Comment: Hi , how can i avoid printing it in the screen, the output of AWK should be redirected to file itself?

Comment: You can do `awk '/^1/ {print substr($0,1,4)"123456789"substr($0,14)}' file > outfile`